Ant Design Charts Next.js Server Error with using require in the lib
I have the "@ant-design/charts" and "@ant-design/plots" installed, however I'm getting the following error:
Server Error
Error: require() of ES Module /node_modules/d3-hierarchy/src/index.js from /node_modules/@antv/g2-extension-plot/lib/utils/hierarchy/partition.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /node_modules/@antv/g2-extension-plot/lib/utils/hierarchy/partition.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

Here's my component:


import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { Chart } from '@antv/g2'

const LineChart = () => {
    const chartContainerRef = useRef(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        const data = [
            { month: 'Jan', city: 'Tokyo', temperature: 7 },
            { month: 'Jan', city: 'London', temperature: 3.9 },
            { month: 'Feb', city: 'Tokyo', temperature: 6.9 },
            { month: 'Feb', city: 'London', temperature: 4.2 },
            { month: 'Mar', city: 'Tokyo', temperature: 9.5 },
            { month: 'Mar', city: 'London', temperature: 5.7 },
            { month: 'Apr', city: 'Tokyo', temperature: 14.5 },
            { month: 'Apr', city: 'London', temperature: 8.5 },
            { month: 'May', city: 'Tokyo', temperature: 18.4 },
            { month: 'May', city: 'London', temperature: 11.9 },
            { month: 'Jun', city: 'Tokyo', temperature: 21.5 },
            { month: 'Jun', city: 'London', temperature: 15.2 },
            { month: 'Jul', city: 'Tokyo', temperature: 25.2 },
            { month: 'Jul', city: 'London', temperature: 17 },
            { month: 'Aug', city: 'Tokyo', temperature: 26.5 },
            { month: 'Aug', city: 'London', temperature: 16.6 },
            { month: 'Sep', city: 'Tokyo', temperature: 23.3 },
            { month: 'Sep', city: 'London', temperature: 14.2 },
            { month: 'Oct', city: 'Tokyo', temperature: 18.3 },
            { month: 'Oct', city: 'London', temperature: 10.3 },
            { month: 'Nov', city: 'Tokyo', temperature: 13.9 },
            { month: 'Nov', city: 'London', temperature: 6.6 },
            { month: 'Dec', city: 'Tokyo', temperature: 9.6 },
            { month: 'Dec', city: 'London', temperature: 4.8 },
        ]

        const chart = new Chart({
            container: chartContainerRef.current,
            autoFit: true,
        })

        chart
            .data(data)
            .encode('x', 'month')
            .encode('y', 'temperature')
            .encode('color', 'city')
            .scale('x', {
                range: [0, 1],
            })
            .scale('y', {
                nice: true,
            })
            .axis('y', { labelFormatter: (d) => d + '°C' })

        chart.line().encode('shape', 'smooth')

        chart.point().encode('shape', 'point').tooltip(false)

        chart.render()

        return () => {
            chart.destroy()
        }
    }, [])

    return <div ref={chartContainerRef}></div>
}

export default LineChart



This is basically pointing to an issue in the component itself which is not editable/fixable. Any help on resolving this is very much appreciated. I'm fighting this for the past 3 hours already.

Like the error says you need to use a dynamic nextjs import, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52939439/dynamic-import-node-module-with-next-js
